# How do I install fglrx?

Tags: 11.04, fglrx

How can I install the fglrx driver nativly in Natty. With support of the new xserver which is used in Natty?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

See here:

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-proprietary-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

After installing fglrx by package manager you also have to activate it by using the "additional drivers" program in system control. But at least for my some compiz effects were broken.

Comment: yes, thats my problem too, does it give another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked it was broken. There is a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/555957

You may want to hold on to the open source drivers or go back to maverick in the meantime.