# How do I install additional drivers?

Tags: drivers

I've just installed Ubuntu and I need either video, wireless, or some sort of other manufacturer (non-opensource) driver. How can I run the tool that will fetch all of these for me? I'd like graphical instructions.

Related:

- [Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-my-graphics-drivers-via-the-command-prompt)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Unity (15.10 and 15.04/14.04/13.04/14.10/13.10/12.10)

Click on the gear icon on the top right corner of your screen and click on "System Settings" from that menu, click on Software Sources (or you can click on the Ubuntu button and search for "Sources":

[image]

and then on the Additional drivers tab:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this selection in the terminal? I changed drivers and now I can only access the terminal.

Comment: @Basil see the top question, there's a link to a CLI version.

Comment: If you can't see the"Software Sources" (a.k.a. "Software & Updates") icon, install the `software-properties-gtk` package.

Comment: I have a graphic card `STRIX-R7370-DC2OC-2GD5-GAMING` but the `Additional Drivers` dialog does not show me any related device / driver. How can I install the driver for my graphic card?

Answer (score 58):

### Unity (12.04)

Ensure that you are connected to the internet, if you are installing wireless drivers then usually you need to be plugged in via an ethernet cable. Click on the Ubuntu logo in the launcher and type *drivers* and click on the icon that appears.

[image: Screenshot of searching the Dash for "drivers". First result selected.]

If you have hardware for which there are supporting drivers to download, they'll show up in this window and allow you to install them. If nothing shows up in this window then you probably don't need drivers installed for your hardware as they come bundled with Ubuntu.

[image: Image of Additional drivers window]

Comment: There was a very good programmer team, creator of the sites touslesdrivers.com (now dead),  maconfig.com(now dead),that became now driverscloud.com. I don't know if anyone knows them. It was a drivers scanning software suggesting drivers to update, but online, for Linux & Windows. I didn't find something as good as it was before they change their name. I was a good complement to the Linux driver tool.

Comment: @Quidam when installing ubuntu do i need drivers to support other thins like wifi etc. just like in windows?

Comment: Yes, you need drivers, with any OS, because drivers are the pieces of software that makes the hardware and the software work together. Which drivers you need depends from your hardware (What's your computer model, your wifi card, etc). With Linux, you have the choice sometimes to get the open-source drivers, or the proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 24):

*to complete the already excellent accepted answer*

**Important:** *Firstly, ensure that you are connected to the internet either wirelessly or via fixed ethernet.*

### Lubuntu

[image]

### Kubuntu

[image]

### Xubuntu

[image]

### and what happens next...

and after selecting *Additional Drivers* (or *Hardware Drivers* in 10.04)

The following briefly appears

[image]

Followed by:

[image]

Choose from the list of offered drivers - click the **Activate** button.

Then reboot.

Comment: The method given for Kubuntu doesn't work for Kubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9):

### Drivers

Unlike Windows, most hardware is natively supported in Ubuntu and does not require separate drivers to work.  Generally speaking, if it works don't worry about a driver not being installed. **Please note:** there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa-demos/+bug/914631/) so that your graphics card will be displayed as `Unknown` in System Settings even if the driver is correctly installed and working--you can safely ignore this (or see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/85318/63478) Q&A for the workaround).

If however something isn't working:

Ubuntu uses a graphical user interface called `jockey` or "Additional Drivers" to manage and install hardware drivers that are not natively supported by Ubuntu.

To open it hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `jockey-gtk`.

A window will then open that will allow you to select additional drivers for sound, video, wireless etc.  Here's a screenshot of this window, I already have several drivers enabled.

[image: jockey]

If something still doesn't work and you don't see a relevant driver in Jockey, please post a specific question including as much information about your hardware and what you have tried!

### Applications

New applications on the other hand--as opposed to drivers--will have to be installed manually.  However, unlike Windows, Ubuntu manages software centrally using *repositories*--in short, you don't have to go find/download software yourself.  Ubuntu Software Center is one option for installing software (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/66447/63478) question) but you can also install from the command line using`sudo apt-get install software-name` (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/4477/63478) question for more information on finding/installing software from the command line).  You can also download Debian packages (`.deb`) from the internet and manually install them (or compile software yourself from source code if you are feeling ambitious)--but it's much safer and more convenient to install from the repositories.  Welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: Jockey has been merged into the software center, could you perhaps update your answer to reflect that?

Comment: this is an old post but still useful; jockey is no longer used as of... 13.04? In any case if you're on 14.10 and probably 14.04 jockey is no longer used.